# Ajax Bad Request 400 Rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, bad-request

I'm getting bad request error 400 using Ajax on Rails.
When i submit my form I have a string to send as parameter from Jquery and i want to retrieve it from params[:assignee] so i can extract the string and save it through my controller.
My controller:

```
    def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)
    @task.user = current_user
    username = params.permit[:assignee]
    @task.assignee = username

    #set_category
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: 'Task was successfully created. '+task_params.inspect}

        #format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: 'Task was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

def task_params
  params.require(:task).permit(:owner, :value, :completed, :category, :date, :assignee)

end
```

And this is my JS:

```
 $( "#new_task" ).submit(function() {
    alert("form: "+assignee);
  //event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
   url: "/tasks",
   type: "POST",
   data: {assignee},
   dataType: "json",
   success: function(data) {
       alert('successfully');
     },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
     alert(xhr.statusText+""+textStatus+""+error);
  }
   });
});
```

assignee is an username selected in a jquery auto-complete form:

```
select: function(event, ui) {
    var terms = split(this.value);
    // remove the current input
    terms.pop();
    // add the selected item
    terms.push(ui.item.value);
    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
    terms.push("");
    this.value = terms.join("");
    assignee=this.value;
    $('input[name=commit]').prop("disabled",false);

    return false;
}
```

My root is "task/" where you can see saved tasks and a form to create a new one.
I searched a lot on the net and I tried them all. How can I do? Thanks so much

Comment: what you get in the browser console?

Comment: The 404 error mean what client unable to find a route. Check your routes.rb.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! It's 400. Console:
http://localhost:3000/tasks/ 400 (Bad Request)

Comment: @AlexBeginner what is inside `assignee` variable? Could you add the output of that variable to the question body?

Comment: assignee is a string

Comment: why you no use a form with `remote: true` param? see this [link](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-for)

Comment: @inye i tried but it still not working. I am going crazy :(

Comment: I'm using che code in response. Now it's a 500 error

Comment: (anonymous function) $.ajax({.....

Answer (score 3):

> 400 Bad Request - The server cannot or will not process the request due
>   to an apparent client error (e.g., **malformed request syntax**, too large
>   size, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes)

Change the `ajax` code to:

```
$.ajax({
   url: "/tasks",
   type: "POST",
   dataType: "json",
   headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'), // Optional
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   data: JSON.stringify({ assignee: assignee }),
   success: function(data) {
       alert('successfully');
   },
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
     alert(xhr.statusText+""+textStatus+""+error);
   }
});
```

`{assignee}` that's a not valid JSON object it should be `{assignee: assignee}`
Also you should add a valid headers, The `'Content-Type'` and (`X-CSRF-TOKEN` optional)

Comment: ok now no error in browser console but Yet I can not see the parameter assignee (as you can see i've "notice task_params.inspect" to inspect what params are passed). The alert shows the error "error".

Comment: `assignee=this.value;` should be `var assignee=this.value;` also check the params with `params.inspect` because `assignee` is outside of `task` key.

Comment: I initialized var assignee at the top

Comment: This is an another question, which not related to the main problem `Ajax Bad Request 400 Rails`. 1 problem => 1 answer that's how stackoverflow works.

Comment: yes i know but the question is still open. It doesn't work, but thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
    $( "#new_task" ).submit(function(event) {
    alert("form: "+assignee);
    var value = $('#new_task').find('input[name="task[value]"]').val();
event.preventDefault();
 $.ajax({
   url: "/tasks",
   type: "post",
   contentType: "application/json",

   data: JSON.stringify({ assignee: assignee, value: value }),
   success: function(data) {
       alert('successfully');
   },
   error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
     alert(xhr.statusText+" "+textStatus+" "+error);
   }
});

});
```

`event.preventDefault();` --> without this, the form is submitted twice.

`var value = $('#new_task').find('input[name="task[value]"]').val();` --> without this, i could lose my form value because of "post tasks" that reminds to task#create